# Permission error for running Python on the back of VBA

Tags: python, excel, vba

I am trying to create a simple excel file with a button to populate the cells from an excel file. The issue I am having is that if I have my excel file open, python can't open the excel due to permission error (since the file is already open). I know a simple way is to create variables in VBA and let python do all the calculations and then pass it back to VBA. And then VBA will populate the cells. That's not what I am trying to do. I have seen people online to be able to keep excel open while run python and populate simultaneously. What am I missing? Is there some way to give permission to the python when opening from the VBA?

Integrating the Python to VBA seems to be fairly simple. I made a module in VBA using this code:

```
Sub RunPythonScript()

Dim objShell As Object
Dim PythonExePath, PythonScriptPath As String
    Set objShell = VBA.CreateObject("Wscript.Shell")
    
    PythonExePath = """C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python37_64\python.exe"""
    PythonScriptPath = "E:\My Documents\Finance\Economy\excel2.py"
    
    objShell.Run PythonExePath & PythonScriptPath
    
End Sub
```

And for python:

```
from openpyxl import load_workbook
wb = load_workbook('Python_Button.xlsm')
ws = wb["Sheet1"]

for i in range (1,21):
    currentCell = "A" + str(i)
    ws[currentCell] = i
wb.save('Python_Button.xlsm')
wb.close()
```

Comment: Instead of running Python from Excel, just run Python to open Excel. Either that or you need a separate workbook that controls both Python and the other Excel book.

Comment: Even if I change the python to open a different excel file and then change that file, even then I can't change the other excel file.  The only way I can change any file is from a python console!

Comment: This might be an XY problem. Can you explain what you are trying to do?

Comment: So I wanted to have a button in Excel to run a python script. Which would also fill up cells in the Excell sheet. I got a feeling that this can be achieved using win32com. Not sure how though.

Comment: That's doesn't describe *what* you are doing. You are describing *how* you want to do it. What does the Python script do? Why can't you use VBA to fill up the cells?

Answer (score 1):

So this would be one way to do it:

```
Option Explicit
    
Sub RunPythonScript() 
 Dim objShell As Object 
 Dim PythonExe, PythonScript As String

 Set objShell = VBA.CreateObject("Wscript.Shell")
 PythonExe = """C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual 
 Studio\Shared\Python37_64\python.exe"""
 PythonScript = """E:\My Documents\Finance\Economy\excel6.py"""
 objShell.Run PythonExe & PythonScript
End Sub
```

And on Python

```
import xlwings as xw
book.sheets["Sheet1"].range('A1').value = 100
```

Now one can add a button in the excel sheet and call the python script to populate the excel.